# jQuery fadeIn Animation Effect on Ajax Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple search form with `Ajax` search suggestion functionality. Everything is working correctly, just trying to add a `fadeIn` animation effect. Right now the suggestion data just quickly pop in.

```
// my ajax
$.ajax({ ... success: searchSuccess, ... });

// show data
function searchSuccess(data) {
    $('#my-results').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $(this).html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Move the `$(this).html(data)` outside the fadeIn. You are fading in the element and then setting its data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `hide` the element first, set your data and do `fadeIn` then,

```
$('#my-results').hide().html(data).fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but somehow it jumps (like some kind of reload) before the data fade in. Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, it is hidden with `style="display: none"`. I think it is grabbing the size of the div displayed data > hiding > showing

Comment: @WayBehind As I could not see your UI, I can guess like, change display none to block. But set opacity 0. And in the js, `$('#my-results').html(data).animate({opacity:1}, 1000);`

Comment: Thanks for the help! This seems to do the trick `$('#my-results').html(data).show({opacity:1}, 1000);`

Comment: @WayBehind Glad to help! :) `.show({opacity` or `.animate({opacity` ?? Because there is no such signature with `show`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105185/discussion-between-waybehind-and-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy).

Comment: The animate didn't work at all, but the `show(1000)` is working! Per your suggestion, I have removed the opacity! BTW I was trying to use the `show` before but I was placing the `show(1000)` before the `html(data)`. Silly me :)